# Is there anywhere in the Torah,where Hashem tells someone to get married to another?

Tags: marriage

Is there anywhere in the Torah,where Hashem tells someone to get married to another?

What if someone said to you: Hashem or an angel told me ,that we are getting married?

Is there anything in the Talmud about this question?

Comment: I don't find this a stupid question. It should be straightforward, conceptually - is there a possuk in Torah (or TaNaCH, if we want to broaden it a smidge) where a person is told through prophecy to marry another? There are actually a number of places where we find marriages that seem overtly "divinely arranged" (of course all events are ordained in heaven) without necessarily being explicitly commanded. Adam and Eve, for example, are never "told" to marry, though it was obviously the correct and appropriate thing to do.

Comment: Other possible places: https://books.google.com/books?id=khjDq8DMHaAC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=did+david+know+that+he+was+supposed+to+marry+batsheva&source=bl&ots=P9s1gvLaGg&sig=NFUJBwMFAqdlUKk0JUOGDVXv4AI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX0-Tw_5XLAhULwGMKHVRKDGEQ6AEITDAI#v=onepage&q=did%20david%20know%20that%20he%20was%20supposed%20to%20marry%20batsheva&f=false Sanhedrin 107a states that David was "destined from creation" to marry Batsheva. Again, it's questionable whether he was told this explicitly or had some sort of "ruach hakodesh."

Comment: I think you should separate the 1st question from the other two. As phrased, it's unclear what your focus really is. Is it halachic or are you asking about what's in Torah / Tanac"h / Talmud?

Comment: Well the question is more about,can someone say to another:The angel or Hashem told me that we are getting married,and if there is anyone in the scripture that,that says something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are thinking of the navi Hoshea who was commanded to marry and whose prophesy involved this. However, this was because Hashem wanted to teach Hoshea a lesson. Hoshea could not bring himself to divorce his (apparently) unfaithful wife. If this is so, how could hashem "divorce" the unfaithful Bnei Yisrael.

As far as your general question, this could involve the entire question of 'navi sheker' and how do we know that what a person is claiming as a message from Hashem is actually true.

We do know that there are no nevi'im nowadays but there are great tzadikim who speak to Eliyahu Hanavi and get told various things.

[Hosea - Chapter 1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16155#v=2&showrashi=true)

> ב תְּחִלַּת דִּבֶּר יְהֹוָה בְּהוֹשֵׁעַ וַיֹּאמֶר יְהֹוָה אֶל הוֹשֵׁעַ
>   לֵךְ קַח לְךָ אֵשֶׁת זְנוּנִים וְיַלְדֵי זְנוּנִים כִּי זָנֹה תִזְנֶה
>   הָאָרֶץ מֵאַחֲרֵי יְהֹוָה:
>
> 2 At the beginning of the Lord's speaking to Hosea, the Lord said to
>   Hosea: Go, take yourself a wife of harlotry and children of harlotry,
>   for the land goes astray from following the Lord.
>
> **Rashi**
>
> **take yourself a wife of harlotry**: Our Rabbis said: This is to be explained according to its apparent meaning: Since he said about
>   Israel, “Exchange them for another nation,” as is explained in
>   Pesachim at the beginning of the chapter entitled האשה, “The woman”
>   (87a).
>
> **and children of harlotry**: For she will bear you children who will be of possible illegitimacy. And Jonathan paraphrased: Prophesy a
>   prophecy about the inhabitants of the cities of idolatry. The word
>   קַח, stated here is an expression of teaching, [derived from לֶקַח,
>   doctrine]. Teach them to repent.

Comment: tzadik speak with Eliyahu hanavi? How?

Comment: @Eagel There are stories in which tzadikim are visited by Eliyahu Hanavi and he gives them messages or teaches them. There are also stories in which he appears and does something for people.